# how to zoom the plot in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I don't know how to operate the plot to be zoomed.
This plot draw random function in real time.
I want to zoom the plot in real time for specified region.
This code is example code in pyqtgraph. This code works right for fixed data.
Is it impossible the plot moving in real time to zoom? 
Would you please help me?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.setWindowTitle('Scroll and Zoomed Plot')

plotScroll = win.addPlot()
plotScroll.setDownsampling(mode='peak')
plotScroll.setClipToView(True)
curveScroll = plotScroll.plot()

dataRnd = np.empty(100)
ptrDataRnd = 0

def updateScroll():
    global dataRnd, ptrDataRnd
    dataRnd[ptrDataRnd] = np.random.normal()
    ptrDataRnd += 1
    if ptrDataRnd >= dataRnd.shape[0]:
        tmp = dataRnd
        dataRnd = np.empty(dataRnd.shape[0] * 2)
        dataRnd[:tmp.shape[0]] = tmp
    curveScroll.setData(dataRnd[:ptrDataRnd])

LinRegionItem = pg.LinearRegionItem([0,100])
LinRegionItem.setZValue(-10)
plotScroll.addItem(LinRegionItem)

win.nextRow()

plotZoom = win.addPlot(title="Zoomed graph for Random plot ")
plotZoom.plot(dataRnd, pen=(255,255,255,200))

def updatePlot():
    plotZoom.setXRange(*LinRegionItem.getRegion(), padding=0)
def updateRegion():
    LinRegionItem.setRegion(plotZoom.getViewBox().viewRange()[0])
LinRegionItem.sigRegionChanged.connect(updatePlot)
plotZoom.sigXRangeChanged.connect(updateRegion)
updatePlot()

# update all plots
def update():
    updateScroll()

timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(50)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** example showing the problem. Also what do you mean by restart?

Comment: Thanks for comment. The "Restart" function was solved as shown below lines.  
    `def RestartPlot():  
        global dataRnd,ptrDataRnd  
        #plotScroll.clear()  
        timer.stop()  
        dataRnd = np.empty(100)  
        ptrDataRnd = 0  
        timer.start(50)`

Comment: I'm not familiar to use markdown scripts. The second question's minimal example cannot be inserted into this place. And I replace new source with 2nd problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also solved this problem. I revised the code as shown below line.

Before revision:

```
curveZoom.setData(dataRnd[:ptrDataRnd])
```

revised code:

```
curveZoom.setData(dataRnd[0:ptrDataRnd])
```

I wonder the convention of the numpy array. 
The meaning of "dataRnd[:ptrDataRnd]" is to specify range from 0th to ptrDataRnd. Am I wrong? 
Please tell me the truth.